# Command-line JSON browser with TUI

Tags: command-line, json

Given a large-ish JSON, browse it interactively in terminal.

```
$ output_long_json
{"packages":[{"name":"ba... <fill up entire screen>
```

It is already possible with repeated invocation of `jq`:

```
$ output_long_json | jq ''
{
  "packages": [
    {...
<better, but it dives in depth-first and I don't see top-level elements>

$ outout_long_json | jq 'keys'
[
  "packages",
  "resolve",
  "target_directory",
  "version",
  "workspace_members",
  "workspace_root"
]
<OK, now I want to enter "resolve" and see what's here>

$ outout_long_json | jq '.resolve | keys'
...
```

But is there maybe TUI way?

Imagined:

```
$ output_long_json | json_browse
-----------
| /
|   packages 
| * resolve
|   target_directory
|   ...

-----------
| /resolve
| * nodes
|   keys

----------
| /resolve/nodes
| * [0]
|   [1]
|   [2]
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are terminal programs for viewing JSON that I've come across, along with some features:

- [jless](https://github.com/PaulJuliusMartinez/jless) (Rust) (MIT) (3.9k stars)

  - Vim-inspired keybindings
  - regex search
- [fx](https://github.com/antonmedv/fx) (Go) (MIT) (16.8k stars)

  - streaming
  - color themes
  - preserves key order
  - preserves big numbers
  - reducer mode, supports JavaScript, Python, and Ruby syntax
  - jq filters
  - mouse support
- [json-tui](https://github.com/ArthurSonzogni/json-tui) (C++) (MIT) (271 stars)

  - small, 400 LOC
  - mouse support
- [jid](https://github.com/simeji/jid) (Go) (MIT) (6.6k stars)

  - "JSON incremental digger"
  - jq syntax
  - suggestion and autocompletion
- [tson](https://github.com/skanehira/tson) (Go) (MIT) (132 stars)

  - archived, last updated in 2019
- [pyfx](https://github.com/cielong/pyfx) (Python) (MIT) (22 stars)
- [nvim-jqx](https://github.com/gennaro-tedesco/nvim-jqx) (Lua) (MIT) (246 stars)

  - Neovim plugin
  - supports YAML
- [ijq](https://sr.ht/%7Egpanders/ijq) (Go) (GPLv3)

  - interactive tool for viewing jq inputs and outputs
- [vim-jqplay](https://github.com/bfrg/vim-jqplay) (VimScript) (Vim license) (86 stars)

  - Vim plugin
  - interactive tool for viewing jq inputs and outputs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone chances on this question from a search engine, I found an answer.

[fx](https://github.com/antonmedv/fx) is a command-line utility that allows TUI-style interactive browsing of JSON data. You can fetch that package through NPM or download a binary from the link.